# /tf sends messages at different timestamp

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a /tf message that seems to send messages at different timestamps. I added comments "// Look here" to highlight the stamps in secs and Im mostly intrigued by the one with the comment "// Look here !!" as the time stamp in secs has absolutely different timestamp. However, the next after that one follows the the pattern as the majority.

[image: image description]

Why does this happen?

```
--
transforms: 
- 
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1305031234        // Look here
    nsecs: 763107844
  frame_id: /kinect
child_frame_id: /openni_camera
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -0.0112272525515
    y: 0.0502554918469
    z: -0.0574041954071
  rotation: 
    x: 0.129908557896
    y: -0.141388223098
    z: 0.681948549539
    w: 0.705747343414
- 
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1305031234           // Look here
    nsecs: 763107844
  frame_id: /world
child_frame_id: /kinect
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 1.28183615112
    y: 0.60716934967
    z: 1.60902340698
  rotation: 
    x: -0.226407331155
    y: -0.209261051914
    z: 0.662704621347
    w: 0.682474993971
 ---
 transforms: 
- 
  header: 
    seq: 0
    stamp: 
    secs: 1551776935     // Look here   !!!
    nsecs: 528851222
  frame_id: world
  child_frame_id: camera_pose
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0543486074629
    y: -0.0490532501685
    z: -0.083467717153
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0249910632545
    y: -0.369232593093
    z: 0.0535471565154
    w: 0.927456436165
---
transforms: 
- 
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1305031234                 // Look here
    nsecs: 773104542
  frame_id: /kinect
child_frame_id: /openni_camera
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: -0.0112272525515
    y: 0.0502554918469
    z: -0.0574041954071
  rotation: 
    x: 0.129908557896
    y: -0.141388223098
    z: 0.681948549539
    w: 0.705747343414
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317512//tf-sends-messages-at-different-timestamp/) by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-03-05**:
Can you post your tree?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
It's likely there are either multiple hosts involved that don't have their clocks synchronised, or a bag is being played together with live nodes.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2019-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn, what do you mean by live nodes?
@EdwardNur, updated my question with the tree,

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
"live nodes" as in: nodes that publish messages that are not part of the bag. That is of course ok, but then `use_sim_time` should probably be used. If the bag contains messages "from the past" (as they probably all do), then not setting `use_sim_time` will cause "real time" to be mixed with old ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
.. stamps, which can lead to issues such as the one you show here.

Whether that is the case here depends of course on you: only you know how you configured your system.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
According to the screenshot of your TF tree, it would appear that you have `rosbag play` running and `camera_pose` is being broadcast by the `/Mono` node.

Are you specifying `--clock`? `/Mono` seems to be using Wallclock, not the clock from the bag.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2019-03-05**:
Nope, not using clock. Will check it out.

**Comment by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) on 2019-03-14**:
@gvdhoorn, setting up --clock didnt work. I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked up this [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/217588/error-in-rosbag-play-despite-setting-use_sim_time-param/). Just by setting the use_sim_time alone didnt work in the beginning.

I completely stopped the roscore, then set the sim_time param and then let all of my stuff run and it seemed to work.

---

Originally posted by [murdock](https://answers.ros.org/users/26483/murdock/) with karma: 75 on 2019-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0